# How do I find and set the directory?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a game in pygame and I have images i'm trying to load but it doesn't work unless I set the directory with OS module, and that would be fine. Except if I want to make it an App the directory is hard coded. How could I do this?

I've tried getting the directory and using the replace function to change the slashes to double slashes but it didn't work.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path


path = Path.cwd()
path1 = path
print(path1)
input()
print(path1.replace("\","\\"))


input("")
```

When I try running the code I get:

```
 print(path1.replace("\","\\"))
                                 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: Be careful using `pathlib.Path.replace`. This [might not have the effect you want](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Answer (score 1):

The backslash (`\`) sign in a string starts an escape sequence. A single back slash sign in a string is `\\`. See [String literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).
To replace a singe `\` by `\\`, it has to be:

```py
print(path1.replace("\\","\\\\"))
```